# Why does adding mut to passed Iterator reference solve this?

Tags: rust

In the following Rust snippet:

```
fn main() {
    let list1: Vec<i32> = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

    let it1 = list1.iter();
    let tens = it1.map(|x| x * 10).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
    println!("{:?}", tens);
    
    let it2 = list1.iter();
    let doubled_from_iter = scale_it_iter(&it2);

    println!("{:?}", doubled_from_iter);
}

fn scale_it_iter(l: &dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    l.map(|x| x * 2).collect()
}
```

[Rust Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9eb4406cda4844275e3d17f56810183)

I get this error:

```
error: the `map` method cannot be invoked on a trait object
   --> src/main.rs:15:7
    |
15  |     l.map(|x| x * 2).collect()
    |       ^^^
    |
   ::: /home/xolve/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:625:15
    |
625 |         Self: Sized,
    |               ----- this has a `Sized` requirement
    |
    = note: you need `&mut dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>` instead of `&dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Adding `mut` as suggested by the compiler solves this. [Rust Playground link for working code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fe4b73a61b0b351d958f51c597f191d2).

I do not understand why it is needed. It's not needed in `main` when I call `it1.map`.

I don't understand the error messages.

1. `` the `map` method cannot be invoked on a trait object `` is solved by adding `mut` to the trait reference. This seems contradictory.
2. How is the message about the `Sized` trait bound related to the error?

Comment: `Iterator::map` mutates the iterator, so you need a mutable reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *"`map` method cannot be invoked on a trait object"* and *"this has a [`Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) requirement"* error messages are because [`map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) *consumes* the original iterator. [`dyn Trait`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html?highlight=dyn#trait-objects) cannot be consumed (they are *unsized* types and cannot be passed to functions by value).

It works for `it1` because 1) its not a trait object, its a concrete type [`Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) and 2) its not a reference so it is consumed.

The reason that `&mut dyn Iterator` works is because [`&mut dyn Iterator` implements `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-13). The effective difference is just the reference is consumed and the underlying iterator is mutated.

---

If you want to follow convention, I'd make `scale_it_iter` *consume* the iterator like so:

```
fn scale_it_iter<'a>(l: impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    l.map(|x| x * 2).collect()
}
```

Comment: Even better regarding convention, the function could accept `impl IntoIterator` and use `l.into_iter()....`. That way one can pass it not just iterators, but also collections or other iterables.

Comment: @kmdreko In snippet with `impl Iterator` I do not need to add `mut` to iterator. The `map` method still mutates the iterator though.