# Contradictory error messages calling .any() on &dyn Iterator vs &mut dyn Iterator

Tags: rust

MCVE (simplified from real code where I may return a raw vec.iter(), or a vec.iter().filter() based on some conditions):

```
let input = vec![1,2,3];
let dyn_iter: &dyn Iterator<Item = &i32> = &input.iter();
let result = dyn_iter.any(|x| *x == 2);
```

Gives error:

```
error: the `any` method cannot be invoked on a trait object
    --> src/main.rs:19:37
     |
19   |     let result: Vec<i32> = dyn_iter.any(|x| x == 2);
     |                                     ^^^
     |
    ::: ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:2507:15
     |
2507 |         Self: Sized,
     |               ----- this has a `Sized` requirement
     |
     = note: you need `&mut dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>` instead of `&dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>`
```

However, if I change & to &mut, then I get the OPPOSITE error:

```
let input = vec![1,2,3];
let dyn_iter: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = &i32> = &mut input.iter();
let result = dyn_iter.any(|x| *x == 2);
```

Gives:

```
error: the `any` method cannot be invoked on a trait object
    --> src/main.rs:19:37
     |
19   |     let result: Vec<i32> = dyn_iter.any(|x| x == 2);
     |                                     ^^^
     |
    ::: ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:2507:15
     |
2507 |         Self: Sized,
     |               ----- this has a `Sized` requirement
     |
     = note: you need `&dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>` instead of `&mut dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>`
```

Here are the last lines of the error messages for comparison. Note how they are exactly contradictory!

```
     = note: you need `&mut dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>` instead of `&dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>`
     = note: you need `&dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>` instead of `&mut dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>`
```

I found a similar question: [Why does adding mut to passed Iterator reference solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65753865/why-does-adding-mut-to-passed-iterator-reference-solve-this), but he is using .map() instead of .any(). When I use .map(), it works just fine:

```
let input = vec![1,2,3];
let dyn_iter: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = &i32> = &mut input.iter();
let result: Vec<i32> = dyn_iter.map(|x| x+1).collect();
```

This runs without errors. So it seems the problem is specific to the any() method? What's going on?

Comment: You can solve this by `(&mut iter).any(...)`. I don't have time to do proper investigation now, but it looks like a diagnostics bugs. The compiler just suggests inverting the mutability [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/36aa7c143672af30bfcca01e5924b326f93fd922/compiler/rustc_typeck/src/check/method/suggest.rs?q=%2Fyou+need+.*+instead+of%2F+repo%3Arust-lang%2Frust#L1148-L1156).

Comment: @AndersonF.Viana The OP explictly refers to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Chayim's comment, the correct syntax (for my example) is:

```
(&mut dyn_iter).any(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error message is really misleading there... the answer is as simple as [Iterator::any has a Self: Sized](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#2505-2508) bound so it is not trait object safe and not usable from a trait object.

The behavior is trivially reproducible, [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc33a797b23861d3dd43561ca732330a):

```
pub trait Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self) where Self: Sized;
}


impl Foo for Vec<u32> {
    fn bar(&mut self) where Self: Sized {}
}

fn main() {
    let input = vec![1,2,3];
    let dyn_iter: &mut dyn Foo = &mut input;
    let result = dyn_iter.bar();
}
```

Comment: map, filter, etc also have Self: Sized bound so I still don't understand. can you explain what's different about them from any()?

Comment: I suspect that it's that `map` and `filter` take `self`, not `&mut self`, so what `Self` refers to is different?

Comment: @muusbolla they take ownership of self that's the only difference. it's still the same issue with them! they have Self: Sized bounds https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754159/9171481 this is explained in the other post you linked to.

Comment: Ah, I finally stumbled upon the other necessary detail: `Iterator` is [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.60.0/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#3676-3691) for `&mut I` where `I: Iterator + ?Sized`.